# replace NA in a data frame with random value from that column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with about 15 columns, and there are missing values NA for some of the rows & some columns.

I found a way to replace NA in a column with a randomly selected element within the same vector, but how can I do this for the entire data frame?

For instance, if a column name is `age`, I can do:

```
age[is.na(age)] <- sample(age[!is.na(age)], sum(is.na(age)), replace=F)
```

I want to write a function that does above for each column in the data frame (15 columns). The problem is how can I index each column? I can't seem to use `df[i,]` in this case.

Comment: Be careful, your code isn't very robust.  The replace=F means that if you ever have a column with more than half of the entries NA, the function will fail.

Comment: the `mice` package has some good functionality for these issues. Decent intro found [here](https://datascienceplus.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `lapply` and `replace`

```
df[] <- lapply(df,function(x) replace(x,is.na(x), sample(x[!is.na(x)],sum(is.na(x)))))
```

Here, we loop over entire dataframe column by column and `replace` the `NA`'s with any of the non-NA's using `sample`.